# Math Equation Web Control?

Tags: math, user-controls

Is there any easy web application or user control that allows math equations to be easily created and stored as a text string?

**Update:** An ASP.NET control would be ideal.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a starting point: http://thornahawk.unitedti.org/equationeditor/equationeditor.php

Comment: THanks! I can't really implement PHP since we're in .NET, but this is a very helpful stating point

Answer (score 2):

There is no short answer to this but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML) has very good coverage of your options including coverage on [MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML) (Math Markup Language)

They list a javascript library, [ASCIIMathML](http://www1.chapman.edu/~jipsen/mathml/asciimath.html),  that works in both Mozilla (Firefox) and IE in conjunction with a display component [MathPlayer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathPlayer).

Answer (score 2):

Galwegian's suggestion doesn't actually do much in PHP, so turning it into an ASP.NET control shouldn't be too hard. The editor is all in Javascript, which you can of course reference from .NET. The PHP code just receives AJAX requests when you click Render Equation and passes them to codecogs.com to create the actual image.

You could either port that bit to .NET, or alternatively use [jsMath](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/examples/Henrici.html) to do the rendering. This isn't quite as pretty as an image rendered by LaTeX, but since it's Javascript you could probably have it constantly update the rendered equation as you edit rather than requiring a button to update it.